# Phonegap $.ajax android parsererr

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I have a basic application that runs fine in the browser and in the emulator, however once I deploy it to my android device my ajax requests stop working and go straight to error.

I noticed this same error originally with the emulator when I was trying to use localhost instead of `http://10.0.2.2/`, which leads me to believe this may be a permissions error.

I have set the whitelist to `<access origin="*" />` for testing purposes.

My ajax call looks something like this

```
$.ajax({    
    url: 'http://mysubdomain.jit.su/myendpoint,     
    dataType: 'json',   
    type: 'GET',    
    beforeSend = function(xhr) {    
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + _credentials);         
    }
});
```

Been banging my head against the desk with this for a bit now so any suggestions welcome!

**EDIT**

Interestingly I switched off hydration and all is now working!

Any thoughts on why this would be the case?

Comment: What's the error you get? Can you share your logcat? Does that request trigger the success or the error callback? You get any errors there?

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this in AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I am using PhoneGap Build, this permission is added by default?